# Website hosted on godaddy sometimes stops loading

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-server, web-applications

I have hosted a website on godaddy. The website is implemented using ASP.NET. The website works fine for a while after that it stops loading (gets stuck at loading and then throws error).
Then when i go to godaddy control panel, in the web.config file, I increase the value of timeout and it starts working. Then stops again after a while and then i have to increase the value of timeout again.
This is the code I change: -

```
<add name="DailyShopping" connectionString="Data 
Source=188.121.44.214;Integrated Security=False;User ID=xxxxxx; 
password=xxxxxx;Connect Timeout=15000;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

This is actually a connection string to a database.

You can see Connect Timeout=15000. Now when after a while website stops working i will increase the timeout value to 16000 then it will start working again. I always have to change the value of timeout in order to make website work but it always stops working after a while.
Why does this timeout issue is occuring?? And is there any permanent solution to this??

Comment: What does this question have to do with SQL Server? I really hope that isn't your server's real IP, username and password as well.

Comment: No this isn't my real username and password.
I used sql server tag because I thought there may be problem with the database connectivity due to which website is not loading.

Comment: If changing the connection string gives you some more operation time it sounds like the Connection Pools are running out of resources (each pool is keyed by connection string). First thing I'd do is ensure that all of your IDisposables (like SqlConnection and SqlCommand) are being used in `using (...) {...}` blocks because it sounds like they're just hanging around.

Comment: >> "gets stuck at loading and then throws error" <<  What is the error??

Comment: I don't remember the error exactly but nowadays it's just getting stuck at loading forever.

Comment: @ZaeemKhaliq Have you asked their support team? Basically you can't increase your timeout since you are using shared hosting service. You need to ask them to increase it for you. If you encounter error again, please advise the error that you get.